# chromedriver looses connection "randomly", KeepAliveFailure

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running automatic tests for our web application. Seemingly randomly it loses connection to webdriver and shows the following exception when it tries to click an element on the site.

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'A exception with a null response was
 thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL 
http://localhost:51838/session/0adcb677d8062f712728d3aeb011e63e/element/
743947cc-ce53-4d82-a020-3ac9d6a6e6af/click.
 The status of the exception was KeepAliveFailure, and the message was:
 The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to
 be kept alive was closed by the server.'
```

Inner Exceptions:

SocketException:

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

IOException:

```
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

WebException:

```
<i>The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.
```

Error Stack Trace:

```
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Submit()
   at ACT.Web.Ui.Tests.PageCommands.DefaultCommand.LoginToAzure(String azureLogin, String azurePassword) in C:\Data\szypr002\My Documents\act\ACT.Web.Ui.Tests\PageCommands\DefaultCommand.cs:line 43
   at ACT.Web.Ui.Tests.StepDefinitions.LoginPageSteps.WhenILoginToActAs(String user) in C:\Data\szypr002\My Documents\act\ACT.Web.Ui.Tests\StepDefinitions\LoginPageSteps.cs:line 26
   at ACT.Web.Ui.Tests.StepDefinitions.LoginPageSteps.GivenICanLoginToAct() in C:\Data\szypr002\My Documents\act\ACT.Web.Ui.Tests\StepDefinitions\LoginPageSteps.cs:line 17
   at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager )
```

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of chromedriver being instantiated in the code?

Comment: @Szyku instead of parts can you update the question with the complete error stack trace?

Comment: @work_ishaan No, only one instance

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding some extra settings to your ChromeOptions, like this:

```
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("--disable-impl-side-painting"); //To fix no such session exception which appears when running tests for a prolonged period
            options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
            options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
            options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Specifically, `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-impl-side-painting` might help with your connection closed issues.